# how to ssh into a remote host and execute a command immediately

Tags: linux

If i've already put public key to remote host. So there is no password input problem.

I want to login a remote machine and execute `screen -r`  immediately. Is there a way to achieve this ?

For example:

```
ssh example.com ;  screen -r
```

But this is wrong since `screen -r` won't send to remote host.

Comment: The `screen` command may require a TTL.  Other commands work fine, but as pointed out in the answers, you need `ssh host "commands"`

Answer (score 13):

When you run a command on a remote host, by default ssh will not allocate a pseudoterminal. If you run an interactive program like screen on a remote host, you must have a pseudoterminal. The `-t` option makes this happen. Try:

```
ssh -t example.com "screen -r"
```

Answer (score 11):

Remove the semicolon from your example:

```
ssh example.com "screen -r"
```

Your not going to get much bandwidth for that particular command though, as it needs an attached terminal in order to execute successfully.

---

*** EDIT 1 ***

To run multiple commands, just string them together separated by semi-colon:

```
ssh example.com "screen -r; ls -al; ps -elfc"
```

---

*** EDIT 2 ***

Still not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish (was `screen -r` just an example, or are you really trying to just chain a bunch of commands together?). In any case, I am amending my answer to cover more possibilities:

To chain random commands together:

```
ssh example.com "ps -elfc; ls"
```

To run some random commands after running screen:

```
ssh -t example.com "screen -r; ls"
```

To specifically run screen and send commands to it:

```
ssh -t example.com "screen -r -X ls"
```

Comment: it returns: `Must be connected to a terminal.` . This is not my want. I want to continue use this host after `screen -r`.

Comment: I assume that by 'continue to use this host', that you mean you want to issue a string of commands. See edit to my answer for that. As I said before, `screen -r` is just not going to work without an attached terminal, and you won't have a terminal if you are running remote commands via ssh.

Comment: @perception, "you won't have a terminal if you are running remote commands via ssh" isn't true--see my answer for clarification.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified my statement with 'by default'. I am keeping my answer as generic as possible since its not entirely clear what the OP really wants to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for replying. My purpose:  Everyday I log into remote host and doing some various work, not a serial specific command. However, Everytime I've need to 1) ssh into host.   2) type command `screen -r` .  I'm wondering if I can do these two thing in one `enter` key press.

Answer (score 3):

You can also echo your command to the remote host:

```
echo "command" | ssh user@host
```

Answer (score 1):

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1

> ssh [-1246AaCfgkMNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D
>        [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
>        [-i identity_file] [-L  [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
>        [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-R
>        [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-w tunnel:tunnel]
>        [user@]hostname [command]

Command is the last parameter.  ; tells the local shell that ssh and screen are two different commands, not that one is a command and the other is an argument.

Not sure if it will work or not since screen is an odd program to do it with, but *ssh blah.com 'screen -r'* is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
ssh root@something 'ls -l'
```

Comment: That's wrong.  The backticks will execute the command *ls -l* then take the output of that and put it as an arguement to *ssh root@something*

Comment: Oops! Typo! I meant ' and not `. Corrected

Comment: This is not my want. I want to continue use this host after `screen -r`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes:

```
ssh example.com 'screen -r'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen who/what are you addressing?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the command you want to run after the host name:

```
ssh example.com screen -r
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
ssh -XY -t user@remote_IP 'ssh -XY -t user@remoteToRemote_IP'
```

you can continue with command `screen -r` or any other at remoteToRemote_IP machine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pass the `-t` flag.

This:

```
ssh -t v tmux attach -t o
```

runs tmux with the specified options (`-t o` means to connect to the session named `o`)

If I run it without the `-t` I get an error:

```
➜  ~ ssh v tmux attach -t o
open terminal failed: not a terminal
```

The quotes are optional. This also works, but involves typing two extra keystrokes:

```
ssh -t v 'tmux attach -t o'
```

By the way my ssh host is called `v` because I added an entry to `~/.ssh/config`. The `v` stands for `vagrant`, and it goes to a user I created instead of the `vagrant` user that ships by default.